# KOA 2 - Compile SASS to CSS using node-sass-middleware

Tags: node.js, sass, koa2

I am trying to get the node-sass-middleware using koa2. There is a module `koa-sass` that works perfectly, but it is using generator.

```
module.exports = function (options) {
  var mw = require('node-sass-middleware')(options);
  return function *(next) {
    yield mw.bind(mw, this.req, this.res);
    yield next;
  };
};
```

> koa deprecated Support for generators will be removed in v3. See the documentation for examples of how to convert old middleware https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/migration.md

**so I want to convert it using async/await**.

here is my code:

```
module.exports = (options) => {
  const sass = require('node-sass-middleware')(options);;

  const middleware = async (ctx, next) => {
    await sass.bind(sass, ctx.req, ctx.res);
    await next();
  }
  return middleware;
};
```

It does note return an error, but it won't compile as well.

**app.js**

```
app.use(sass({
  src: path.join(__dirname + '/scss'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname + '/public/stylesheets'),
  outputStyle: 'compressed',
  indentedSyntax: false
}))

app.use(require('koa-static')(__dirname, 'public'))
```

**Folder structure**

```
public
|--scss
|  |--style.scss
|--public
|  |--stylesheets
|  |  |--style.css
app.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe wrapper should be like this:

```
module.exports = function (options) {
    const sass = require('node-sass-middleware')(options);
    return (ctx, next) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            sass.call(sass, ctx.req, ctx.res, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(next());
                }
           });
       });
    };
};
```

Also, you could take a look at https://github.com/vkurchatkin/koa-connect

Comment: It works. Thanks. But I am confused as to why async/await in this won't work?

Comment: Because `await sass.bind(sass, ctx.req, ctx.res);` is not an actual function call it returns (and never uses) bound middleware function that previously was handled as the yield from the generator.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this answer might be late, but for anyone who stumbles across this:

### [koa-sassy](https://github.com/dominicegginton/koa-sassy)

> Modern Koa middleware for SASS

### Install

```sh
npm i koa-sassy
```

### Getting Started

```js
const Koa = require('koa')
const sassy = require('koa-sassy')
const app = new Koa()

app.use(sassy(__dirname + '/sass'))
```